# Workflow rule based on Account custom Date field not firing

Tags: workflow, date, cross-object

I created my WFR on the Contact object. "Arrival__c" is an Account custom date field that should trigger an email alert to all Contacts of said account on the arrival date. There is also a picklist value filtering records whose Account custom Source value is 'somevalue', and a basic email opt-out filter.

This rule worked for me in my dev edition, but I have trouble getting it to fire in the live org. I am pretty new at this so perhaps I just don't understand formula logic well enough.

Account.Arrival__c = TODAY() && NOT( ISPICKVAL( Account.Custom_Source__c , 'somevalue') ) && HasOptedOutOfEmail = FALSE

Comment: You want a change to the `Account` field to process child records? You can't use a `Workflow Rule` for that, and it wouldn't be on the child object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the namespace prefix of your org to custom fields
code as follows:

```
Account.NamespacePrefix__Arrival__c = TODAY() && NOT( ISPICKVAL( 
    Account.NamespacePrefix__Custom_Source__c , 'somevalue') ) && HasOptedOutOfEmail = FALSE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please do not leave a signature under your posts; that's just noise and and a link to your profile is automatically added by the system anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As per you workflow rule on the Contact object. "Arrival__c" is an Account custom date field that should trigger an email alert to all Contacts of said account on the arrival date.
You workflow is not because of this email.
You need to configure  email deliverability setting in your live org 
setup-> Email Administration -> deliverability 
Change the access level to system email only
this is help to fire your workflow rule.

Thanks,
Amol Salve.
Salesforce Developer

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I did get my WFR working on our live org using a lookup field on the Contact object that reads the Arrival date from the Account and uses it as a time trigger for the action.

I need the email to come from the Salesforce Users who are owners of the account records in our system, as the email is currently being sent from one person — the employee who uploads the records daily and assigns them to team members; this team member has Administrator privileges as well, and has been designated as the "Default Workflow User" in our org.